# How to disable smart cast highlight Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

IDE : Android Studio 3.3

I am doing kotlin smart casting in RecyclerView adapter on ViewHolder.

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder as ViewHolder
```

Now every mention of viewholder is being highlighted, with text on hover saying "Smart Cast to ..." This is not a problem but really annoying. How can I disable this highlight feature?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the IDE prefererences, see:

> *Editor → Color scheme → Kotlin → Smart-casts → Smart-cast value*

If you want to disable value smart-cast highlighting, just uncheck *Background*.

You may want to configure the other kinds of smart-casts, too.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> Java/Kotlin -> Classes and Interfaces

You should be able to find color scheme for classes here.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using `holder as ViewHolder`, try using `if (holder !is ViewHolder) throw Exception()` or `if (holder !is ViewHolder) return`.

Comment: It wasn't about the code but the IDE settings as in accepted answer.